# Force console application to print even when busy in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console-application

I have a simple console application as follows:

```
private static void Main (string [] args)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Initializing context...");
    Database.Context.Initialize();

    System.Console.WriteLine("Creating server...");
    var server = new Server();
    server.OnStarting += Server_OnStarting;
    server.OnStarted += Server_OnStarted;

    System.Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
    server.Start();
}

private static void Server_OnStarting (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Server_OnStarting.");
}

private static void Server_OnStarted (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Server_OnStarted.");
}
```

**SERVER START METHOD:**

```
public bool Start ()
{
    bool result = false;

    lock (this._SyncRoot)
    {
        if (!this.Running)
        {
            this.Stopwatch.Reset();

            this.RaiseOnStarting();

            this.Running = true;
            this.Terminate = false;
            this.ThreadObject = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(this.ProcessInternal));

            this.Stopwatch.Restart();
            this.ThreadObject.Start();

            this.RaiseOnStarted();

            result = true;
        }
    }

    return (result);
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image: Console Output]

Out of the three `Console.WriteLine` calls in `Main`, only the first gets printed immediately. This is understandable since everything in `Database.Context.Initialize` happens on the same thread. However, the printing of `Creating server...` and `Starting server...` are delayed and clump together with the `Server_OnStarting` and `Server_OnStarted` messages. The call to the constructor is not threaded but the call to server.Start internally launches a thread, initializes some sockets, etc. However, the events `OnStarting` and `OnStarted` are fired on the **SAME** thread so the threading aspect of it SHOULD NOT matter.

It seems, that after `Initializing context...` is printed, no matter where I put the call to `Console.WriteLine`, it does not update the console window until server.Start returns after firing both events.

Is there a way to force the console to update while waiting for the server to start?

Comment: Is it possible that instantiating `Server` and calling `Server.Start` are completing quickly, causing the messages to appear to be "clumped together"?  If you control the `Server` class, does the behavior continue if you put Thread.Sleep calls in the constructor and `Start` methods?

Comment: Console.Out.Flush() flushes the output buffer. I would try that, but drf's explanation is plausible in that the operations are completing fast enough that they appear to write the messages at the same time.

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @drf: Yes, it changes when I use `Thread.Sleep` in the constructor but only if I use Troy's suggestion of using `Console.Out.Flush` as well.

Comment: @TroyP.: Thanks. That seems to help only if the constructor takes a long time (which it doesn't).

Comment: Can you post the Server code (constructor and `Start` method)?  `Console.Write` should immediately write to the console; the AutoFlush property of the underlying `TextWriter` is true, meaning a manual call to `Console.Out.Flush` should have no effect.  The code sample and the fact that `Thread.Sleep` had an effect suggest that the Server instantiation and `Start` methods are returning quickly enough that the messages appear to be written at the same time.

Comment: @drf: Just posted the server code.

Comment: I see nothing in that `Start` code that's going to take any appreciable amount of time to execute. It looks like all of the delay is in `Database.Context.Initialize();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to force the console to update while waiting for the server to start?

The console behaves this way by default; in fact, there is no (supported) mechanism to force it to behave differently.  When the Console.Out property is initiated, the [`AutoFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the underlying `TextWriter` is set to true.  The documentation for `AutoFlush` indicates this explicitly (emphasis added):

> For example, set AutoFlush to true when you are writing to a device where the user expects immediate feedback. Console.Out is one of these cases: **The StreamWriter used internally for writing to Console flushes all its internal state except the encoder state after every call to StreamWriter.Write.**

(Note the `AutoFlush` cannot be queried directly since the actual implementation uses a thread-safe wrapper; however, you can use the debugger or reflection to check that the value of `((Console.Out as TextWriter.SyncTextWriter)._out as StreamWriter).AutoFlush` is true.)

---

Back to the original problem:

> It seems, that after Initializing context... is printed, no matter where I put the call to `Console.WriteLine`, it does not update the console window until `server.Start` returns after firing both events.

Let's look at what `Server.Start` actually does:

1. Enters a lock (presumably non-blocking since the server is not started)
2. ** Raises OnStarting event**
3. Starts a thread
4. Restarts a stopwatch
5. ** Raises OnStarted event**
6. Returns

None of these tasks are particularly intensive.  The delay between the OnStarting and OnStarted invocations is likely to be in the microsecond range.

**The three status messages will appear to be printed simultaneously because no appreciable time elapses between the instantiation of the server, entering `Server.Start` method, and returning from `Server.Start` method.**

Comment: Thanks. After stepping through the code again, it appears your dissection is spot on. I wonder what made me think otherwise in the first place. That would make this question pretty useless for others.